# Splitting a string using variable offset

Tags: r, string

I want to get all substrings of size *n* and and offset *o* from a string.

For example, given `"abcdef"` and substrings of size = 3, offset = 1. I want to obtain a set with `"abc","bcd", "cde", "def"`.

In Mathematica, this can be done with `Partition` or `StringPartition`.

Is there a similar function in R?

Comment: What role does offset play? I can see that they're all 8 consecutive characters...

Comment: I think `offset` refers to how many characters to skip after taking each substring, e.g. using offset of 2 would skip `bcdefgh1`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just write a wrapper (thanks @thelatemail):

```
subs = function(x, size, offset){
  nc    = nchar(x)
  first = seq(1, nc-size+1L, by=offset)
  last  = first + size -1L
  substring(x, first, last)
}


subs("abcde",3, 1)
[1] "abc" "bcd" "cde"
```

Comment: Isn't `substring` already vectorized, as in `substring(x, 1:(nchar(x)-2), 3:nchar(x))`

Comment: @thelatemail D'oh, I didn't think to check, figured the op had tried and it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: last  = first + size -1

Comment: Thanks for the answer